# Indirect function with an operator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this formula to get the position of the value of the last non-empty cell:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))`

I would like to find the last position in row 13:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($13:$13<>""),COLUMN($13:$13))`

But I would like the row to be dynamic:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($13:$13<>""),COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1&":"&$A$1)))`

I'm having trouble inserting INDIRECT function within `$13:$13<>""`. I tried

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT($A$1&":"&$A$1&"<>"&char(34)&char(34))),COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1&":"&$A$1)))` but I'm getting a #REF! error. Thanks.

Comment: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT($A$1&":"&$A$1)<>""),COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1&":"&$A$1)))`

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think about this possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An abbreviated form of R1C1
[image]

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/(INDIRECT("R"&A1,)<>""),INDIRECT("R"&A1,))
```